# Convert array of hash to single hash in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am trying to convert an array of hashes into a hash with key as one of the elements of hash in the array.

For example: `a = [{"active_accounts": 3, "id": 5}, {"active_accounts": 6, "id": 1}`

I want to convert this array to

```
a = {5: {"active_accounts": 3}, 1: {"active_accounts": 6}}
```

I have tried doing it by looping over the array and accessing individual hash for a particular key but that doesn't seem to work. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you've tried.

Comment: 'response = Hash.new
a.each do |key|
  response[key[:id]] = {"active_accounts": key[:active_accounts]}
end
response'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.each_with_object({}) {|obj , hash| hash.merge!(Hash[obj[:id], Hash["active_accounts",obj[:active_accounts]]])}

# {5=>{"active_accounts"=>3}, 1=>{"active_accounts"=>6}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It sure did Rangnath. :)

Answer (score 1):

Safe variant, mapping to arrays (same `"id"` are expected and treated properly):

```
a.group_by { |e| e.delete("id") }
```

Exactly what you asked:

```
a.group_by { |e| e.delete("id") }
 .map { |k, v| [k, v.first] }
 .to_h
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mudasobwa. Great Help.

Answer (score 1):

One more possible solution)

```
a.map { |hash| [hash.delete(:id), hash] }.to_h
#=> {5=>{:active_accounts=>3}, 1=>{:active_accounts=>6}}
```